# Convert plain text data into an object with arrays based on formatting

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

What is the best way to convert plain text data like:

```
[group a]
a
b
c
[group b]
a
d
f
```

Into an object...

```
{
groupA: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
groupB: ['a', 'd', 'f']
}
```

The plain text data will vary in length, but the structure will always be represented like:

```
[parent group]
child item 1
child item 2
...
```

Comment: Do you have control of the string input?

Comment: To some degree... the end user can create parent groups and child items from the frontend - which is very controlled, but there is an automated process on the backend which creates additional plaintext that is dumped into a formatted list (Not the list above). Both need to land into a formatted document

Comment: If you could change it you can take the shape of a json in string `const str = {"group A":['a','b','c']}` then use `JSON.parse(str)` https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Start off by `split()`ting with `[` as the separator which should give you as many groups as there are in the string:

```
[ '', 'group a]\na\nb\nc\n', 'group b]\na\nd\nf' ]
```

(2) Use `.filter()` to remove undesired empty strings:

```
[ 'group a]\na\nb\nc\n', 'group b]\na\nd\nf' ]
```

(3) Now use `.map()` to transform each group using `]` or `\n` as separators:

```
[ [ 'group a', '', 'a', 'b', 'c', '' ], [ 'group b', '', 'a', 'd', 'f' ] ]
```

(4) Use `.filter()` to remove undesired empty strings:

```
[ [ 'group a', 'a', 'b', 'c' ], [ 'group b', 'a', 'd', 'f' ] ]
```

(5) Lastly use `.reduce()` and `Object.assign()` to convert each group into a key-value pair:

```
{ 'group a': [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ], 'group b': [ 'a', 'd', 'f' ] }
```

**Please note** that the fragment,

```
.split(' ').map((a,i) => i === 0 ? a : a.toUpperCase()).join('')
```

is what converts `group a` into `groupA`, etc

**DEMO**

```js
let data = `[group a]
a
b
c
[group b]
a
d
f
[group c]
g
h
t`;

let obj = data
          .split(/\[/)
          .filter(v => v) 
          .map(v => v.split(/\]|[\r\n]+/)
          .filter(v => v))
          .reduce((acc,val) => 
              Object.assign(acc,
                {[val[0].split(' ').map((a,i) => i === 0 ? a : a.toUpperCase()).join('')]:val.slice(1)}),{});

console.log( obj );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split and reduce

```js
const string = `[group a]
a
b
c
[group b]
a
d
f`

const list = string.split(`\n`)
let saveKey;
const obj = list.reduce((acc,cur) => {
  if (cur.startsWith('[')) { 
    const groupLetter = cur.match(/ (\w+)\]/)[1].toUpperCase()

    saveKey = `group${groupLetter}`;
    acc[saveKey]=[];
  }  
  else {
    acc[saveKey].push(cur);
  }  
  return acc
},{})
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can grab all the lines of text and reduce the lines by parsing and determining if it is a key or a value. Your accumulator needs to store both the results and the current key.

```js
const
  parse = (text) =>
    text.trim().split('\n')
    .reduce((acc, line) => {
      const match = line.trim().match(/^\[(.+)\]$/);
      return match
        ? { ...acc, key: match[1] }
        : { ...acc, result: { ...acc.result,
            [acc.key]: [...(acc.result[acc.key] ?? []), line.trim()] }
          };
    }, { result: {}, key: null }).result,
  data = parse(document.querySelector('#data').value);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }

#data { display: none; }
```

```html
<textarea id="data">[group a]
a
b
c
[group b]
a
d
f</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of the original string by splitting on `\n`, then loop through and create the object:

```js
const str = `[group a]
a
b
c
[group b]
a
d
f`

const arr = str.split('\n')
const obj = {}
let curHeader

arr.forEach(el =>
{
  if(el[0] === '[')
  {
    let frmtEl = el.substring(1, el.length-1)
    let frmtElArr = frmtEl.split(' ')
    curHeader = frmtElArr[0] + frmtElArr[1].toUpperCase()
    obj[curHeader] = []
  }
  else
  {
    obj[curHeader].push(el)
  }
})

console.log(obj)
```